# Connect to NordVPN using Python in MacOS without using command line tools

Tags: python, python-requests, ip-address

So, I wanted to get a few search results for Google without getting blocked for a Machine Learning app. I want to use a python script to rotate my IP Address while making requests to avoid getting blocked by Google. I can't seem to get the python script working. I don't a API endpoint from which I can connect to NordVPN.

I tried to figure out the endpoint using the chrome extension and inspecting its webpage. But it was of no use.

Currently I'm stuck at this issue.
My code:

```py
import requests

access_token = 'my-secret-token'

# Get a list of available server groups
server_groups_url = "https://api.nordvpn.com/server"
headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                      'Chrome/89.0.4389.82 Safari/537.36',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,fr;q=0.8,es;q=0.7',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'DNT': '1',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
        'TE': 'Trailers',
        'Authorization': f"Bearer {access_token}"
    }
server_groups = requests.get(server_groups_url, headers=headers).json()

# Choose a server (e.g. the first server in the list)
hostname = server_groups[0]['domain']
```

the hostname in the code returns something like this: 'p119.nordvpn.com'
I don't know how to connect to this VPN using python code. Can someone help me ?